# Get Sobject In pic List

Tags: apex

i want to know how to get Sobject in list.

pleas can any one help me.

thanks In Advance.

Comment: Parth, could you please detial your question or provide some context such as possibly the code you've already written?  You can simply add sObjects to list like you can add primitive data types to lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May this example help you

```
<apex:page controller="objectList" >
      <apex:form >
        <apex:SelectList value="{!val}" size="1">
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!Name}"></apex:selectOptions>
        </apex:SelectList>
      </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

//========

```
 public class objectList{
      public String val {get;set;}
      public List<SelectOption> getName()
      {
        List<Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();    
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        for(Schema.SObjectType f : gd)
        {
           options.add(new SelectOption(f.getDescribe().getLabel(),f.getDescribe().getLabel()));
        }
        return options;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getGlobalDescribe()` method in `Schema` namespace to get the list of `sObjects`.

```
List<string> SObjectList = new List<string>();
for(Schema.SObjectType objTyp : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values()){
    String name = objTyp.getDescribe().getName();
    // Exclude all the unwanted Sobjects e.g. History, Share etc..
    if(!name.containsignorecase('history') && !name.containsignorecase('tag') && !name.containsignorecase('share') && !name.containsignorecase('feed')){      
        SobjectList.add(name);
}
```

You can use this SObjectList. [Schema namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm) for your reference.

Hope it helps.